# Why does my React Redux TypeScript app work everywhere except iPhone 6 iOS 12.0.1 (where it is a blank white screen)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My basic static React Redux TypeScript app works locally on Windows, and then it also works when I deploy to GitHub Pages for every device I've tested *except* iPhone 6 iOS 12.0.1 (where it is a blank white screen).

I've researched many articles, such as:

- [React/redux app renders blank screen on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116068/react-redux-app-renders-blank-screen-on-safari/61201183#61201183)
- [React/Node Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222722/react-node-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token/55235029#55235029)
- [Why deployed react app on gh-pages is showing blank page on different browsers while showing correctly on my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606883/why-deployed-react-app-on-gh-pages-is-showing-blank-page-on-different-browsers-w)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57027870/470749
- https://community.netlify.com/t/react-application-builds-deploys-into-a-blank-page/2571
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/061d1e46fcd4766d38b45499c3d29cfaa2b7d0af/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6

Most of them try to solve the case where *all* devices show a white page. But that's not my scenario.

Others talk about how older browsers need polyfills, but I've already added try/catch blocks around my use of `fetch`.

I've also tried changing to `"homepage": "."` in `package.json`, but again, I don't think that's related to the issue because most browsers already work, so I know that the assets are being accessed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've experienced this multiple times, on various iOS devices, on a project I'm working on. Curious, on the blank/white pages is your UI still interactable? (long press, click, text select, etc..) We grew accustomed to nick-naming it "Ghost Mode", and it had to do with various elements being absolutely positioned and safari's webview doing weird renderings.

Comment: @DrewReese It's a completely blank page, so there is no UI. I just tried clicking and long-pressing, etc, and don't notice anything interesting. Please upvote the question and click Follow if you like it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, in our case, all we saw was a blank white page as well, but we could still click buttons (since we knew where they were) and interact. This only occurred on a couple pages, ever. Our fix was to apply a `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` CSS on *some* of the components to kick the iOS device into using hardware acceleration to render the UI/webview. This is a link we've in our code documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your ideas. I finally figured out how to view the error message, and now it makes sense: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61215326/470749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I remembered that I could use the free http://xip.io/ service to browse from my iPhone to the "local" React server hosted on my Windows machine.

That way, I could see error messages that wouldn't be visible on production (at GitHub Pages).

I discovered that the error was **"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: IntersectionObserver".**

So the solution would be to use a polyfill.

See helpful links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55767479/470749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59368511/470749
- https://github.com/mhartington/lazy-load-image/issues/1#issuecomment-372384646
- https://webkit.org/blog/8582/intersectionobserver-in-webkit/
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver

"IntersectionObserver API is supported on iOS Safari since 12.2." That explains why it worked on other iPhones but not mine.

Comment: Yeah! Apple is great at making seemingly random fixes/changes to safari in each major iOS update (sometimes even with minor version bumps).